# Jasper report not showing detail section

Tags: jasper-reports

I have designed a report in iReport and now I am using it in my application.

The problem is that the report is generated showing all the data except the detail section data. There is no database connectivity problem, as the column header shows data which is coming from database. Only the detail section of the report shows nothing, neither data from database nor any static data.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Is your header section in a subreport?  If so, and you're passing the main report datasource to the subreport, it will have advanced the current record 'pointer' of the datasource past your data, and your detail section will be blank.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put all your data in one Band to avoid these kind of errors